# How to create Image gallery Metabox in wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field, metabox

I want to create a metabox like woocommerce product gallery.

[image]

I search on google find out related tutorial, plugin, example but unfortunately i don't get anything. So please, anyone can help me. solved this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally like [Advanced custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) for Meta Fields

They have a ["premium" gallery plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/gallery-field/), that for small amount of money, is very useful and works well

Another option is the free [attachments plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/attachments/) , Have a read through the documentation and you will see how to create a custom instance of attachemnts that you can use as a gallery.